# Is it possible to delay booting the system after the user has pressed the power button?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to delay the time to load the kernel after the user has pressed the power button by 10 seconds.
Reasons for this is a machine we have built which requires other components to start sending data to the computer before the kernel loads. The power button for all the electronics is common.

Comment: Which part of the boot process do you want to delay? Are you doing a network boot (TFTP)? Are you mounting the root filesystem over the network? Or is it some daemon that requires other machines to be online? What bootloader do you use, what distribution?

Comment: ask the electronics guys about time delay relays.

Comment: @hildred - we are currently using a relay for this. Wanted to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should define what exactly booting means to you.

If you want to delay the moment the kernel is starting to run, you'll need to configure the boot loader. I guess (but I am not sure) that GRUB is flexible enough to be configurable for that purpose.

If you want to delay the moment the Linux system is starting to initialize some server (including a login server, or a session manager), you'll need to configure the `init` program (or the `systemd` ...)

If you need to delay the network connection, it is also possible (thru scripts in `/etc/network/interfaces`)

The system boot is not some instantaneous transition.

At last, you might buy some cheap hardware which delays the power by 10 seconds, or configure your BIOS for that.

YMMV.